# Problem installing php5-cli on ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, php5

I want to install php5-cli on ubuntu but i keep getting this error

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
php5-cli is already the newest version.
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-2.6.31-14
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 31 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up php5-cli (5.2.10.dfsg.1-2ubuntu6.3) ...
dpkg (subprocess): unable to execute installed post-installation script: Exec format error
dpkg: error processing php5-cli (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of php-pear:
 php-pear depends on php5-cli | php4-cli; however:
  Package php5-cli is not configured yet.
  Package php4-cli is not installed.
dpkg: error processing php-pear (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                          Errors were encountered while processing:
 php5-cli
 php-pear
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

What should i do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you show me output of this command:
`dpkg -l | grep php` 
Seems yout wanted to isntall php4 before.

--
Regards,
Robert

Answer (score 0):

You might try the `--fix-broken` option with `apt-get`.